# How to insert a TimeStamp into Ms-Access using java?

Tags: java, ms-access, timestamp

I would like to insert a java Timestamp into an msaccess database but I am getting an error which is listed below. The ms-access field has been set to a date datatype. Any advise would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Here's my DAO class method:

```
public void addSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal, Timestamp saleTimestamp) 
                        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

     Statement myStatement = getConnection();
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp)"
                + " VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"','"+saleTimestamp+")";

     myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
     closeConnection();
```

My DTO method:

```
public void storeSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal, Timestamp saleTimestamp){
        DAO dao = DAO.getDAO();
         try {
          dao.addSale(saleDetails, saleTotal, saleTimestamp);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sale.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

My Timestamp  method:

```
    public Timestamp addTimestamp(){ 
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
```

And Error:

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in string in query expression ''2012-11-10 09:30:57.174)'.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:287)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your query. Try putting your single-quote at the end of `saletimestamp`

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp)"
                + " VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"','"+saleTimestamp+"')";
```

Comment: Hey thanks Mob..getting another error now though :-  [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.